# Tensorflow 2.0 GPU Internal memory out of error

Tags: python, tensorflow, gpu

I am trying to run my python script using a remote server's GPU that is shared by other users.

The script throws a memory out of error even before it reaches the model training section..

This is the error that I am getting. The server has 3 GPU's however, I am only using a single GPU that is not being used by other processes. Hence I have set "CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES" to be "0", the GPU not in use.

This is the error that I am getting.

```
2020-04-15 15:22:01.870082: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1697] Adding visible gpu devices: 0
2020-04-15 15:22:01.870161: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library libcudart.so.10.1
2020-04-15 15:22:02.748227: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1096] Device interconnect StreamExecutor with strength 1 edge matrix:
2020-04-15 15:22:02.748273: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1102]      0 
2020-04-15 15:22:02.748283: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1115] 0:   N 
2020-04-15 15:22:02.749326: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1241] Created TensorFlow device (/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0 with 58 MB memory) -> physical GPU (device: 0, name: Tesla V100-PCIE-32GB, pci bus id: 0000:d8:00.0, compute capability: 7.0)

2020-04-15 15:22:02.768792: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/eager/execute.cc:573] Executing op RandomUniform in device /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0
2020-04-15 15:22:03.335483: F ./tensorflow/core/kernels/random_op_gpu.h:232] Non-OK-status: GpuLaunchKernel(FillPhiloxRandomKernelLaunch<Distribution>, num_blocks, block_size, 0, d.stream(), gen, data, size, dist) status: Internal: out of memory
Aborted (core dumped)
```

I don't understand why I am running out of error. There are at least 16GB of RAM in this GPU and the model has not even started training yet.

Appreciate everyone's help

Comment: "Created TensorFlow device (/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0 with 58 MB memory)"  . It is having only 58 MB memory which might not be sufficient. Try to increase it .

Comment: I’m not sure how to increase it ? Although I had set the memory growth option to true in the python script